# Promises within a loop: TypeScript + Angular + IndexedDB

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, indexeddb, angular-promise

I'm working on a data synchronization service that is pulling down data from a web service and then storing it in IndexedDB.

I'm doing something like this in my TypeScript Angular Service:

```
this.http
    .post(postUrl, postData)
    .success((data: any, status, headers, config) => {

         console.log("post success");
         console.log("results:");
         console.log(data);

         var records = data.Records;
         var promiseStack = [];

         for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {

             var element = records[i];
             var key = this.dataService.getKeyFromElement(objectStoreConfig, element);

             console.log("key: " + key);

             this.dataService.keyExists(objectStoreConfig, key).then((update) => {

                 if(update){
                     // TODO: put
                     promiseStack.push(true);
                 } else {
                     console.log("using dataService to add to objectStore...");
                     console.log("adding: " + key);
                     this.dataService.add(element, objectStoreConfig).then((result) => {
                         promiseStack.push(result);
                     });
                 }
             });

         }

         this.q.all(promiseStack).then((result) => {
             console.log("done adding/updating all.");
             deferred.resolve(result);
         });
    })
    .error((data, status, headers, config) => {
    });
```

I am getting a `post success` in the console, along with each returned `record` `key` that I anticipate. The trouble is with the asynchronous calls to my `DataService`. The `this.dataService.add` function is what actually creates a transaction and adds records to IndexedDb.

The output in my console (and in the state of IndexedDB - has just one record with a key of `188`) indicates that this code sample *only* calls the `add` function on my `DataService` for the last element in `records`.

Console output:

```
post success
results:
Object
key: 78 
key: 194
key: 188
done adding/updating all. 
using dataService to add to objectStore...
adding: 188
using dataService to add to objectStore...
adding: 188
using dataService to add to objectStore...
adding: 188
```

How can I structure my code differently to make the for loop "wait" for each asynchronous call to be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Approach 1 (only works if you are targeting ES6)**

if you are using TypeScript 1.5 you can just use `let` instead of `var` to declare your element and key variables:

```
let element = records[i];
let key = this.dataService.getKeyFromElement(objectStoreConfig, element);
```

The problem is that `element` and `key` are on the scope of the function not the for loop so every time the for loop iterates it is just replacing `element` and `key` variables instead of creating new variables. If you use `let` then the variables will be on the scope of the for loop.

See [What's-new-in-TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript) for more details.

**Approach 2**

Alternatively you could also use Array.forEach instead of a for loop as that would also fix the scoping problem:

```
records.forEach(function(element) {
    //...
});
```

Comment: Note: You can't use `let` in for loops unless compiling to ES6.

Comment: Right. This makes sense. Assuming compiling to ES6 isn't an option for me, is there another way around the scope issue?

Comment: You can use this when you are compiling to ES5 or 3 too. Quote from the wiki page I linked: "ES6 let and const declarations are now supported when targeting ES3 and ES5."

Comment: Unless it only works for if statements and not loops. But I don't see any mention of that

Comment: Note: using Array.forEach instead of a for loop would also fix the problem...bet `let` is way cooler

Comment: Changing the `var`s to `let`s resulted in: `error TS1153: 'let' declarations are only available when targeting ECMAScript 6 and higher.` when compiling.

Comment: weird. Are you using TypeScript 1.5?

Comment: I am. Perhaps, it's the gulp-typescript compiler I am using that causing the conflict. In any case, `Array.forEach` solved it for me! If you'd like to answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: Edited my answer to include using array.ForEach. Note that you also need to pass the typescript option to gulp-typescript if you want to override it's default TS version. e.g.: `typescript: require('typescript')`

Comment: @rob see here for an example of the error message when using `let` in a for loop: http://goo.gl/ukHRQ2

Comment: @rob I should clarify my statement that when targeting < ES6 you can use `let` in for loops, but not when the variable is referenced in a function within that block scope (as in this question and in the example I gave).

Comment: @DavidSherret ok I guess it's not supported yet. Do you know of anywhere that they document which ES6 features are supported?